# Replace carriage returns \n with real carriage in android app

Tags: php, android

I have an Android app that retrieves values from a servers database and displays them in the app but carriage returns are coming back as \n but I need them to act as carriage that will place text below onto a new line.

I first post data to my server to store in database like this:

```
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['body']);
```

Then I encrypt the text before storing in database like this

```
$encryptedBodyText = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $body, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
```

I now get the data from the database and then JSON it to android

```
$decryptedBody = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($body), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
```

but when I show this data in the android the new lines are shown as \n instead of actual new lines.

How can I replace the \n so they are actual new lines in java

I've tried

```
String t = sharedBodyText.replace("\n",System.getProperty("line.separator"));
bodyText.setText(t);
```

and it doesn't work but if I change to

```
String t = sharedBodyText.replace("gg",System.getProperty("line.separator"));
bodyText.setText(t);
```

it does work if there is "gg" in the body text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing `\n` with `System.getProperty("line.separator")` in Android side

Try this:

```
text.replaceAll("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it works for any other text e.g. gg but for \n it's just ignoring it

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe server sending something else like "\\n" or "\\\\n" . try those too

Comment: another thing, do you use json_encode method on the server side?

Comment: yes I'm using json_encode to send the response. i checked the output and it is \n so not sure why it doesn't get replaced

Comment: I tried 2 slashes text.replaceAll("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator")); and it worked.